# Use MSBuild Targets to copy files recursively from NuGet package

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task

I have a `.targets` file in my NuGet package build folder which is then automatically included in the project that consumes the NuGet package.

I want this `.targets` file to copy some folders on post-build. The following script shows how that is done, but the output I get is wrong because `%(RecursiveDir)` starts at the first wild-card which I used for the version number of the package.

My question: How can I specify the version of MyPackage in the `.targets` file dynamically so that I can remove the first wildcard?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- MyPackage.* should be replaced by MyPackage.1.0.0.4534. But the version is set by NuGet.exe pack -Version -->
      <FilesToCopy Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\MyPackage.*\myfolder\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)\myfolder\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you avoid the use of the version by using [MSBuildThisFileDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) instead. That would give you the directory where the .targets file is so you can change the include to work relative to that directory and not have to use the version number.

Comment: Also if you have a targets file which is going to be imported by every user's projects you should not use 'reserved' names like "AfterBuild" what if the user also defines a target named AfterBuild? Instead use something like `Target Name="PrettyUniqueTargetName" AfterTargets="Build"`

Comment: @MattWard I will accept this as an answer. I didn't know about these properties.

Comment: @stijn I didn't know about that option. I only found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having to the package version you could use the [MSBuildThisFileDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx) property instead.

The MSBuildThisFileDirectory property gives you the directory where the .targets file is so you can change the <FilesToCopy> element to use a path relative to that directory and you do not have to use the version number.

```
<FilesToCopy Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)myfolder\**\*.*"/>
```